# How to split a string to get the last item in braces?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split a string to extract the last item in braces.

For example if I had the string

```
'Stud Rd/(after) Ferntree Gully Rd (Scoresby)'
```

I would like to split it into the components

```
('Stud Rd/(after) Ferntree Gully Rd', 'Scoresby')
```

So far I've written the following regex to do this

```
re.search(r'^(.*) \((.*)\)$', string)
```

However this breaks in the case of an input like

```
'Bell St/Oriel Rd (Bellfield (3081))'
```

Which I would like be split into

```
('Bell St/Oriel Rd', 'Bellfield (3081)')
```

Is there a better way then this to approach this problem?

Comment: How would you like 'Bell St/Oriel Rd (Bellfield (3081))' to be split?

Comment: try and be more specific when you say "into the components".  Into what components?  The last item in parenthesis?  I'm not certain I understand which components you are trying to split it into.

Comment: @BenBeirut I've edited the question to include that.

Comment: additionally, your title says braces yet there are no braces *{ }* in your strings.  Did you mean parenthesis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lazy regex:

```
(.*?) \((.*)\)[^()]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ8xI8/1)

Examples:

```
>>> reg = r'(.*?) \((.*)\)[^()]*$'

>>> s = 'Bell St/Oriel Rd (Bellfield (3081))'
>>> re.findall(reg, s)
[('Bell St/Oriel Rd', 'Bellfield (3081)')]

>>> s = 'Stud Rd/(after) Ferntree Gully Rd (Scoresby)'
>>> re.findall(reg, s)
[('Stud Rd/(after) Ferntree Gully Rd', 'Scoresby')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex pattern and work with **match** object(returned by `search` function) in proper way:

```
import re

str = 'Bell St/Oriel Rd (Bellfield (3081))'
result = re.search(r'^(.*?) \((.*?)\)$', str)

print(result.group(1,2))   # ('Bell St/Oriel Rd', 'Bellfield (3081)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this scheme, given `t` being your text:

```
last = re.findall('\([^())]+\)', t)[-1]
```

The regex searches for an opening parenthesis, then take everything that is neither opening nor closing parenthesis, and then matches the closing parenthesis. Since there could be more than one like this, I use `findall` and take the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This works assuming you don't have any parenthesis prior to the last chunk.

```
var = 'Bell St/Oriel Rd', 'Bellfield (3081)'.split('(')
var[-1] = var[-1][:-1]
```